# Which service is registered for certain interface on D-Bus?

Tags: d-bus, polkit

I know PolKit uses `org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.AuthenticationAgent` interface to connect to authentication agent. I want to know which service is registered for this interface. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. First of all, I should ask about bus name, not interface. But in my case, I sould not care even about bus, because authentication agent registeres itself for polkit with appropriate method, so it may have bus name like `:1.223`. It just says "hey, polkitd, please redirect all authentiation requests 
to this bus". Best way to find current authentication agent is grep security log (the one from syslog) to find polkit report about registered agent:)